# What does it mean that telnet uses port 23?

Tags: transport-protocol, command

On the [IANA Transport Protocol Port number registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml), you can see that telnet connects to port 23. However, telnet takes a port number as an argument. For example, [you can access the HTML of google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544857/how-to-telnet-google-using-command-prompt) by first connecting to port 80

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

and then requesting the html code with

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Following the above command, does telnet connect to port 80 or port 23? What does it mean that telnet is assigned to port 23?

Comment: A telnet client is often (ab)used for other purposes as a *tool at hand* since it just initiates a supposed telnet session (which usually doesn't do harm with other protocols) and then simply pipes text. However, you are confusing a software tool used for connecting a simple text console over telnet with the actual application-layer protocol, and applications and protocols above the transport layer are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 4):

It means that the standard port assigned to telnet is 23. It is the default port.

If you install a telnet server with a default configuration it will listen to port 23. Accordingly if you use a telnet client without specifying a port, it will try to connect to the port 23 of the destination.

It also means that no other service should use this port. The fact that there is a central authority - the IANA - that assigns ports avoids conflicts, and allow everybody to knows which port it is supposed to connect to when trying to reach a particular service.

The ports below 1024 are reserved and should only be use by the services for which they have been assigned by IANA.

Now telnet is a bit special, because a telnet client can be used to "manually" connect to different kind of services, like a SMTP server or even an HTTP server, this is why it is broadly used to test connectivity to those services by specifying the port used, like in your example.

In this case it doesn't use port 23, but use the custom port specified.

It works because those services works in a similar way, by sending commands and response in plain text.